# How to read steering angle with Elm327 Wifi/Bluetooth

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii, elm327

I have elm327 v2.1 bluetooth and wifi usb dongle. I want to read steering angle from a car.

OBD2 PID standards do not include this data.
So I cannot get them by asking PID.

I tried to sniff the traffic , but I wasn't able to do it with this hw yet. With AT commands I used ATMA command to read CANBUS communication inside the car, but it mostly includes OBD2 PID type messages.

Answer (score 0):

CAN protocol control block in every hardware's has a block which it name is can id filter and can id mask. this block filter can massages, and just  access the massages that device need , this help micro controllers  to don't wasting time on Unnecessary packets.
so ELM327 cant sniff traffic ,because can filter block dont let that to see traffic
it just see the packets that can id filter access , the packets that them id is 7xx